# reload a python script using crontable

Tags: python, linux

I am using python to import data, but I would like to improve the robustness of my script.
I added a command to reload the script if it crashes, but I had a problem with: `ps -edf`

In fact I launched my script and I used `ctrl+z` to stop it. And when I use `ps -edf` I found that the process is always present.

My questions: there is another way to check if the process is running or not? and why when I use `ctrl+z` the PID still there. Could I run the python script as a service ?

ps: I couldn't stop the script by using only `ctrl+c` that's why the use of `ctrl+z`

Comment: `ctrl-z` only pauses a process. It doesn't kill it. If you do `fg` it will resume the program.

Comment: @Farhan.K thanks for the info,there is a command to show if the process is really running or paused?

Comment: If you did `crtl-z` you can use the `jobs` command. It should say `stopped` if the process still exists but is paused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a python app as a linux service. See the link below, I believe you can help.

http://devopspy.com/linux/python-script-linux-systemd-service/

Hope this helps! ;)